# Read firebase doc and copy the data into dart list

Tags: arrays, flutter, list, firebase, dart

How can I read the data of my Firebase document and put the data in a local list/array?

[my firebase docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LgeR.png)

Comment: Check out this https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage. Though you can now find the docs for flutter officially on firebase docs too.

Answer (score 0):

To get all data from Firestore.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      print(value.docs);
      for (var element in value.docs) {
        print(element.id);// you will get all ids here
        
      }
    });
```

If you want to upload one particular data from Firestore.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        
        .where("uid",
            isEqualTo: 'your_uid')
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      print(value.docs);
      for (var element in value.docs) {
        print(element.id); // single id of that collection
        
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this once....
check if this is the same u looking for

```
List<String> list=[];
    final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users").get();

    for(int x=0;x<snapshot.docs.length;x++)
      {
        list.add(snapshot.docs[x].id);
      }
    print(list);
```